# Appcelerator app crashing on iPhone X with iOS 12 beta 11

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, ios12

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please bear with me.

I have an Appcelerator app built with Xcode 9.4 / SDK 7.0.3 which work on iPhone X, iPhone 6 etc. with iOS 11.x but crashes on iPhone X with iOS 12 beta 11.

Any pointers to the reason for the crash?

**Relevant portions of crash log**

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000002159959e8
    VM Region Info: 0x2159959e8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 2847513065  Bytes before following region: 47474200
    REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
    Stack                  000000016bd74000-000000016bdfc000 [  544K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 8
--->  GAP OF 0xac8e0000 BYTES
    unused shlib __TEXT    00000002186dc000-000000021870a000 [  184K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ... this process

Thread 2 name:  KrollContext<kroll$1>
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore 0x0000000220f8027c 0x220804000 + 7848572
1   JavaScriptCore 0x0000000220f801a4 0x220804000 + 7848356
2   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d120 0x220804000 + 430368
3   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d134 0x220804000 + 430388
4   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d0cc 0x220804000 + 430284
5   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d134 0x220804000 + 430388
6   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d134 0x220804000 + 430388
7   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d134 0x220804000 + 430388
8   JavaScriptCore 0x000000022086d134 0x220804000 + 430388
9   JavaScriptCore 0x0000000220865a1c 0x220804000 + 399900
10  JavaScriptCore 0x0000000220edd3f0 0x220804000 + 7181296
11  JavaScriptCore 0x0000000221094068 0x220804000 + 8978536
12  JavaScriptCore 0x000000022089b284 0x220804000 + 619140
13  MyProdApp 0x0000000104e574c4 0x104e3c000 + 111812
14  CoreFoundation 0x00000002195bb660 0x219496000 + 1201760
15  CoreFoundation 0x0000000219497980 0x219496000 + 6528
16  CoreFoundation 0x0000000219498564 0x219496000 + 9572
17  Foundation 0x0000000219f4519c 0x219f26000 + 127388
18  MyProdApp 0x0000000104e50410 0x104e3c000 + 82960
19  MyProdApp 0x0000000104e51078 0x104e3c000 + 86136
20  Foundation 0x000000021a0613b0 0x219f26000 + 1291184
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000002191cd2fc 0x2191c2000 + 45820
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000002191cd25c 0x2191c2000 + 45660
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000002191d0d08 0x2191c2000 + 60680
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way for us to read this crash log. It's not symbolicated or anything so it's all just gibberish at this point.

Comment: Hey, it's Hans from Appcelerator! I agree, please add a symbolicated log and (if possible, would really help) the code that causes the crash. Then we can open a JIRA-ticket and fix it before the GA release of iOS 12. Thx!

Comment: Following a comment on ticket https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-26406, I tested the app with SDK 6.3.0 and it works without crash.

But using SDK less than 7.0.3 breaks the Webview and App communication. Any solution / suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar crash with my titanium application in ios12.
As requested by donnywals and Hans knöchel i've symbolicated the log.

The simulator does not seem to be affected by this problem (real devices only)

### Probable cause:

```
14  MyApplication           0x0000000104453094 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 110740 (KrollBridge.m:432)
15  MyApplication           0x0000000104459640 -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 136768 (KrollContext.m:103)
16  MyApplication           0x000000010445bbb0 -[KrollContext invokeOnThread:method:withObject:callback:selector:] + 146352 (KrollContext.m:1065)
17  MyApplication           0x0000000104453254 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 111188 (KrollBridge.m:452)
18  MyApplication           0x00000001044540b8 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 114872 (KrollBridge.m:0)
19  MyApplication           0x000000010445c874 -[KrollContext main] + 149620 (KrollContext.m:1262)
```

### Full crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 273DA187-754B-498B-B6A0-F9A2A48B9163
CrashReporter Key:   e54932b550f96832a65276093add14c1b2c04fbe
Hardware Model:      iPad6,7
Process:             MyApplication [471]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/54E187A3-B589-428E-994F-868028FFFD5B/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
Identifier:          com.myapplication
Version:             2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.myapplication [600]


Date/Time:           2018-09-18 23:24:40.4051 +0200
Launch Time:         2018-09-18 23:24:39.7584 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.0 (16A366)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001669c89e8
VM Region Info: 0x1669c89e8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1527548393  Bytes before following region: 82834968
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_TINY            000000010b800000-000000010b900000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
--->  GAP OF 0x5ffc8000 BYTES
      Stack Guard            000000016b8c8000-000000016b8cc000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [471]
Triggered by Thread:  8

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   CoreText                        0x0000000187c476b4 ConvertSettingsToOTFeatures+ 788148 (TInlineVector<unsigned int, 30ul> const&, TFontFeatureSettingList const&, bool, TInlineVector<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, 30ul>&, KerningStatus*, FeatureDefaults) + 1252
1   CoreText                        0x0000000187c47654 ConvertSettingsToOTFeatures+ 788052 (TInlineVector<unsigned int, 30ul> const&, TFontFeatureSettingList const&, bool, TInlineVector<std::__1::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, 30ul>&, KerningStatus*, FeatureDefaults) + 1156
2   CoreText                        0x0000000187c29b2c TOpenTypeMorph::ShapeGlyphs+ 666412 (SyncState&, bool*) + 724
3   CoreText                        0x0000000187ba8240 TShapingEngine::ShapeGlyphs+ 135744 (TRunGlue&, AnnexTableFlag, __CFString const*) + 160
4   CoreText                        0x0000000187bcea08 CTFontTransformGlyphs + 432
5   UIFoundation                    0x000000018e48684c -[NSCoreTypesetter _NSFastDrawString:length:attributes:paragraphStyle:typesetterBehavior:lineBreakMode:rect:padding:cgContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:scrollable:syncAlignment:mirrored:boundingRectPointer:baselineOffsetPointer:wantsTextLineFragments:applicationFrameworkContext:] + 3120
6   UIFoundation                    0x000000018e482d44 -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:context:forceClipping:styledTextOptions:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:wantsTextLineFragments:validatedAttributedString:firstNonRenderedCharacterIndex:foundSoftHyphenAtEOL:enginePathUsed:] + 1112
7   UIFoundation                    0x000000018e501e38 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 3104
8   UIFoundation                    0x000000018e4870b0 -[NSAttributedString+ 24752 (NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 568
9   UIFoundation                    0x000000018e49ee30 -[NSAttributedString+ 122416 (NSStringDrawing) size] + 76
10  MyApplication           0x0000000104512148 -[TiUILabel sizeForFont:] + 893256 (TiUILabel.m:68)
11  MyApplication           0x0000000104512278 -[TiUILabel contentWidthForWidth:] + 893560 (TiUILabel.m:87)
12  MyApplication           0x0000000104511978 -[TiUILabelProxy contentWidthForWidth:] + 891256 (TiUILabelProxy.m:17)
13  MyApplication           0x000000010447fed0 -[TiViewProxy autoWidthForSize:] + 294608 (TiViewProxy.m:876)
14  MyApplication           0x0000000104480bd8 -[TiViewProxy minimumParentWidthForSize:] + 297944 (TiViewProxy.m:1002)
15  MyApplication           0x0000000104480de0 -[TiViewProxy minimumParentHeightForSize:] + 298464 (TiViewProxy.m:1019)
16  MyApplication           0x0000000104480558 -[TiViewProxy autoHeightForSize:] + 296280 (TiViewProxy.m:950)
17  MyApplication           0x0000000104481300 -[TiViewProxy minimumParentHeightForSize:] + 299776 (TiViewProxy.m:1046)
18  MyApplication           0x00000001045cd478 -[TiUIScrollViewProxy autoHeightForSize:] + 1660024 (TiUIScrollViewProxy.m:202)
19  MyApplication           0x00000001045d04f8 -[TiUIScrollView handleContentSize] + 1672440 (TiUIScrollView.m:289)
20  MyApplication           0x00000001045d0130 __43-[TiUIScrollView setNeedsHandleContentSize]_block_invoke + 1671472 (TiUIScrollView.m:236)
21  MyApplication           0x0000000104573a9c __TiThreadPerformOnMainThread_block_invoke + 1292956 (TiBase.m:249)
22  MyApplication           0x0000000104573e74 TiThreadProcessPendingMainThreadBlocks + 1293940 (TiBase.m:357)
23  MyApplication           0x0000000104573c84 __TiThreadPerformOnMainThread_block_invoke.206 + 1293444 (TiBase.m:287)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018390a6c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018390b484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001838b79ec _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e611bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e5c084 __CFRunLoopRun + 1964
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e5b5b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
30  GraphicsServices                0x00000001860cf584 GSEventRunModal + 100
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b025f558 UIApplicationMain + 212
32  MyApplication           0x000000010443ef9c main + 28572 (main.m:30)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018391bb94 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a5ced0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a5c3a8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e60fb0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e5be4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183e5b5b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x000000018484f6a4 -[NSRunLoop+ 34468 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x000000018484f550 -[NSRunLoop+ 34128 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b01bcac0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001849823b0 __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefcfc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  KrollContext<kroll$1>
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b8eb27c JSC::LLInt::setUpCall+ 7848572 (JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 292
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b8eb1a4 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall+ 7848356 (JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 76
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d8120 llint_entry + 29952
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d0a1c vmEntryToJavaScript + 300
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b8483f0 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall+ 7181296 (JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 424
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba7a0fc JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall+ 9482492 (JSC::ExecState*) + 452
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d8bac llint_entry + 32652
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d8134 llint_entry + 29972
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d84e0 llint_entry + 30912
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d8134 llint_entry + 29972
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d0a1c vmEntryToJavaScript + 300
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b846fe4 JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram+ 7176164 (JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 9620
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba22218 JSC::evaluate+ 9122328 (JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 316
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1f9634 JSEvaluateScript + 472
14  MyApplication           0x0000000104453094 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 110740 (KrollBridge.m:432)
15  MyApplication           0x0000000104459640 -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 136768 (KrollContext.m:103)
16  MyApplication           0x000000010445bbb0 -[KrollContext invokeOnThread:method:withObject:callback:selector:] + 146352 (KrollContext.m:1065)
17  MyApplication           0x0000000104453254 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 111188 (KrollBridge.m:452)
18  MyApplication           0x00000001044540b8 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 114872 (KrollBridge.m:0)
19  MyApplication           0x000000010445c874 -[KrollContext main] + 149620 (KrollContext.m:1262)
20  Foundation                      0x00000001849823b0 __NSThread__start__ + 1040
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a5cf24 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001838ac0ac _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 64
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001838aca08 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001838ba824 _dispatch_worker_thread + 352
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a5cfd8 swtch_pri + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aecf88 sched_yield + 16
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1cd93c bmalloc::Mutex::lockSlowCase+ 387388 () + 108
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1cadb8 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 376248 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 164
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1cee70 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 392816 () + 176
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1ce5a4 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 390564 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1d0050 std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 397392 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a67f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183ae4d48 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b8f34 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 302900 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1a00f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 200948 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2004
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b179a38 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 43576 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b179dd8 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 44504 () + 216
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b714c WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 295244 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b86b4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 300724 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  JSC Heap Collector Thread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183a67f0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183ae4d48 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b8f34 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 302900 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1a00f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 200948 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2004
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b179a38 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 43576 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b179dd8 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 44504 () + 216
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b714c WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 295244 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b1b86b4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 300724 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec2fc _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aec25c _pthread_start + 48
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183aefd08 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000106dee4e8   x1: 0x0000000106dee4e8   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001b43d8668
    x4: 0x0000000106de5bc0   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x000000016be21208   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000000bd0513d   x9: 0x00000001081a0000  x10: 0x000000018ba47638  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000002  x13: 0x0000000040000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000108259600
   x16: 0x0000000183addd60  x17: 0x0000000000000cf3  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016be21370
   x20: 0x000000016be213f0  x21: 0x00000001b43d8668  x22: 0x0000000106e00000  x23: 0x0000000106e00000
   x24: 0x0000000108207930  x25: 0x000000016be21670  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0xffff000000000000
   x28: 0xffff000000000002   fp: 0x000000016be21360   lr: 0x000000018b8eb1a4
    sp: 0x000000016be212f0   pc: 0x000000018b8eb27c cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Comment: We're experiencing this exact issue also. Affecting pretty much all of our apps (20+). Any clues @Hans?

Comment: I created a test project that reproduces this error and filed a JIRA bug report. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5895

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the similar issue for my application as well.
My application is running on the simulator. But, application crashes as soon as I launch the application on the device.

Machine environment
Mac OS: 10.13.6 High Sierra
XCode: 10.0 (10A255)
iOS: 12.0
Titanium CLI: 7.0.6
Titanium SDK: 7.4.0.GA